# MarkLogic: how to generate unique document/xml file name

Tags: marklogic

I'm new to MarkLogic.

Here is my requirement:

I have two entities: Staff, Department.
One staff belongs to one department.

For XML, the schema will be:

SomeStaff.xml:

```
<Staff>
  <Name>Lee</Name>
  <Title>VP</Title>
  <DepartmentId>someUniqueURI</DepartmentId>
</Staff>
```

department/someUniqueURI.xml:

```
<Department>
    <Name>IT</Name>
</Department>
```

So, here is my question:

I want to same XML and let MarkLogic generate the file name, for example: I want to save:

```
<Department>
    <Name>IT</Name>
</Department>
```

and MarkLogic will generate a unique URI for it, and return the uri to client.

How can I process this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just write a bit of code:

```
declare function add-dept ($dept as element(Department))
    as xs:string
{
    let $uri := "/departments/" || xs:string (xdmp:random())     (: or some GUID generator :)
    let $_ := xdmp:document-insert ($uri, $dept)
    return $uri
};
```

Call this function where you want to store a new Department document:

```
...
let $dept-id := add-dept ($new-deptartment)
let $new-staff := create-staff ($name, $title, $dept-id)
return add-staff ($new-staff)
```

Writing the create-staff and add-staff functions is left as an exercise for the reader.  This will commit the new department and staff documents atomically.

Comment: Thanks, Ron :) based on my known, xdmp:random will generate a random number from 0 to '64 bits long'. so that's means if I want to get a unique URI, I should use 'GUID generator'? is there any build-in generator? thanks.

Comment: There is not a builtin GUID generator that I know of (unless they added something in ML 7).  The point is that you can make the URI be anything you like as long as it's unique in the database.  If it were me, I'd probably just make the URI be: "/departments/" || $dept/Name/fn:string() || ".xml".

Answer (score 3):

[sem:uuid-string](https://docs.marklogic.com/7.0/sem:uuid-string) function can be used to generate unique GUID. This function was introduced in ML7